# Using arrays in Rhino to group a bunch of widgets

Tags: javascript, java, android, rhino

How do you group a bunch of widgets in a rhino js array? The method I use which adds them one by one in the grid layout wont work with the library without complexity. So how can I store the buttons in an array and then use the arrays .length property to one by one place all the widgets in an array. I am storing android widgets such as an android button and I don't use arrays for widgets. But it is mandatory

Comment: Nevermind I found the answer I was looking for